# Returning a boolean when a string is anywhere a list

Tags: python

I am trying to be able to return a boolean when part of a string is present from a list of strings, so for example here a data set:

```
"issues": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "fields": {
        "labels": [
          "customer:asdf",
          "hello"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "fields": {
        "labels": [
         "icanthearyou",
         "hellotoyou"
        ]
      }
    },
     "id": "3",
     "fields": {
       "labels": [
         "customer:num2",
         "hellotoyou"
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

i am currently grabbing data from this set like so:

```
def grab_data(self, data):
    created_values = list((item['id'],
                           # key
                           True if "customer:" is in item['fields']['labels'] else false 
                           #fromcustomer boolean
                          ) for item in data['issues'])
```

But obviously the above line `True if "customer:" is in item['fields']['labels'] else false` only works if one of the labels is only "customer:"

So to be clear how would I grab data **in this format** i have above `list((item['labels']) for item in data['issues']` to see that one of the `labels` has this string "customer:" within any entry and return true...

id 1 and 3 should return True and id 2 return False.

So expected value should be [True, False, True]

Comment: Show expected value

Comment: Note that code of the form `True if a in b else False` is really just a long way to write `a in b`. That's already True or False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your original list a little bit to make it a valid Python list variable, but one way to solve this is to `join` all of your labels together into one string, then search that string for "customer:".

```
def filter_issues(issues):
    return [ "customer:" in ' '.join(d["fields"]["labels"]) for d in issues]


issues = [{"id": "1", "fields": {"labels": ["customer:asdf", "hello"]}},
          {"id": "2", "fields": {"labels": ["icanthearyou", "hellotoyou"]}},
          {"id": "3", "fields": {"labels": ["customer:num2","hellotoyou"]}} ]

print(filter_issues(issues))
# Prints: [True, False, True]
```

The reason I used a space in the join instead of just an empty string, is because otherwise something like `["abccust", "omer:foo"]` would pass.